# Google Geocoding API billing issue

Tags: r, google-geocoding-api

I required service of >2500 requests made on Google Geocoding API. For this, I have made a billing account by submitting my card information. However, when I access the API through my registered API Key, the code repeatedly runs into the OVER QUERY LIMIT error at around 2500 requests. Before reaching near 2500 requests, it ran smoothly. Why is this error occuring despite that billing has been enabled?

I have read about OVER QUERY LIMIT from link below and optimized the code accordingly by pausing after every request, so this might not be the issue
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

**EDIT**
I am using the standard billing plan. Not the premium one

Comment: sometimes it can take a few minutes for the API to register the changes; are you still getting this issue?

Comment: Yes issue persists

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is still persistent you should reach out to [Google Cloud support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing).

Billing support is free of charge and you can get help during 24h.

https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have asked Google support on this. Expecting to hear from them in a  few days